# Error message when enabling 2-factor authentication for NPM

Tags: npm

I'm attempting to enable two-factor authentication for npm. When prompted for my password after executing `npm profile enable-2fa`, the following is returned:

> npm ERR! code EAUTHIP
>
> npm ERR! Unable to authenticate, need: Basic,Bearer

Does anyone know what this is telling me?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

In my case it was giving me:

```
npm ERR! code EAUTHIP
npm ERR! Unable to authenticate, need: Basic
```

And the problem was because the password was incorrect.